# ¿Cómo mandar parámetros de C# mediante el onclientClick en aspx mediante Javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net

Quisiera saber la forma de que pueda mandar un parámetro que obtengo de mi codebehind en c# a un  método de tipo onclientClick y en javascript:

Aspx

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpSearch" runat="server"  >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'   Font-Bold="True" CommandArgument="<%# Container.ItemIndex %>" CommandName="Select" href="javascript:ShowPopup('divVideo','background1');"  OnClientClick="addVideo('<%# Eval("Url") %>');"></asp:LinkButton><br />
                <asp:Label ID="LabOtherInfo" runat="server" ForeColor="Gray" Text='<%# Eval("Desc") %>' ></asp:Label>
                <hr />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

CodeBehind:

```
    var data = result.List.Select(r => new
    {
        Name = r.titulo,
        Desc= r.description,
        Url=r.url
    }).ToList();

    rpSearch.DataSource = data;
    rpSearch.DataBind();
```

La consulta y el resto del metodo lo hace correctamente pero al momento de mandar uno de mis parametros mediante javascript me sale el siguiente error:

```
Descripción: Error al analizar el recurso requerido para dar servicio a esta solicitud. Revise los detalles de error de análisis específicos y modifique el archivo de código fuente en consecuencia. 

Mensaje de error del analizador: Etiqueta de servidor incorrecta.
```

Comment: No entendí bien "pero al momento de mandar uno de mis parametros mediante javascript me sale el siguiente error:" Cuando se produce ese error?